# changing XMLgregorianCalender default format to "yyyyMMdd"

Tags: java, jaxb, gregorian-calendar, xmlgregoriancalendar

need assistant,  i need to change the default format (2017-01-18) for `XMLGregorianCalendar` to example "20170118"  , i have tried a lot of examples through here but its not helping

```
private static SimpleDateFormat formats = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");

public static XMLGregorianCalendar unmarshal(String value) {
    try {
        return toXMLGregorianCalendar(formats.parse(value));
    } catch ( ParseException e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you cannot do that. If you take a look into the class `XMLGregorianCalendar`, you'll find that the `toString()` method just call the `toXMLFormat()` and the `toXMLFormat()` doesn't provide any possibility for format customization.

> ```
> public String toXMLFormat() {
>
>     QName typekind = getXMLSchemaType();
>
>     String formatString = null;
>     // Fix 4971612: invalid SCCS macro substitution in data string
>     //   no %{alpha}% to avoid SCCS macro substitution
>     if (typekind == DatatypeConstants.DATETIME) {
>         formatString = "%Y-%M-%DT%h:%m:%s" + "%z";
>     } else if (typekind == DatatypeConstants.DATE) {
>         formatString = "%Y-%M-%D" + "%z";
>     } else if (typekind == DatatypeConstants.TIME) {
>         formatString = "%h:%m:%s" + "%z";
>     } else if (typekind == DatatypeConstants.GMONTH) {
>         formatString = "--%M" + "%z";
>     } else if (typekind == DatatypeConstants.GDAY) {
>         formatString = "---%D" + "%z";
>     } else if (typekind == DatatypeConstants.GYEAR) {
>         formatString = "%Y" + "%z";
>     } else if (typekind == DatatypeConstants.GYEARMONTH) {
>         formatString = "%Y-%M" + "%z";
>     } else if (typekind == DatatypeConstants.GMONTHDAY) {
>         formatString = "--%M-%D" + "%z";
>     }
>     return format(formatString);
> }
> ```

### Is there any work-around solution?

Well, if you just want to get a string of type `yyyyMMdd` from a `XMLGregorianCalendar` object, you can do:

```
XMLGregorianCalendar c = YourCalendarHelper.unmarshal("2017-01-18");
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
String str = format.format(c.toGregorianCalendar().getTime());

System.out.println(str);  // 20170118
```

By the way, if an exception raised during the conversion, DO NOT catch it unless you know you're 100% sure how to handle it. Throw it through the method declaration, so that the caller this method is aware of the potential failure.